# Summon command is not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to summon a horse with this command:

```
/summon EntityHorse ~0 ~1 ~0 {Attributes:
[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:30.000},{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0.3375},
{Name:horse.jumpStrength,Base:1.0}],Type:0,Tame:1,SaddleItem:{id:329}}
```

It reports:

> Unable to summon object.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure if you need `0` after `~0`. Did you use this website? https://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/how-to-summon-any-horses-in-minecraft/ It was last updated 3 years ago, so things may have changed.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a previous version of the command.  My answer is for if you are playing latest release (1.12.1).

`EntityHorse` is pre 1.11.  The current name to summon is `horse`.  This also means `Type` is no longer required.

The saddle portion of the command is not correct either.

Here is an updated command:

```
/summon horse ~ ~1 ~ {Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:30.000},{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0.3375},{Name:horse.jumpStrength,Base:1.0}],Tame:1,SaddleItem:{id:"minecraft:saddle",Count:1}}
```